# Can I declare a variable AFTER select in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sybase

I'm using a proprietary ASPX Query Editor that FORCES me to start every query with SELECT. It will not allow me to send any code to the database where the first word is anything other than SELECT.

So I'm curious, is there a way I can declare and set variables in a select query AFTER the SELECT statement?

```
declare @var datetime
set @var = (select sysdate from dual)
select @var from dual
```

Application error: "SQLQuery should start with 'SELECT' keyword."

To be clear, this is an error from the application interface, not an Oracle error.

EDIT: The code snippet above isn't PL/SQL (I don't think) but I used it to show the error.

Comment: That doesn't look like PL/SQL to me. Does this editor have it's own language and somehow translates that?

Comment: @stickybit no it accepts native PL/SQL. Honestly I saw that snippet elsewhere and it might be TSQL, but I used it as an example to show the application error.

Comment: What will your variables be used for? Are you actually trying to run a PL/SQL block within a query, or just avoid repetition of fixed values, or something else? From your previous comment; How does it accept native PL/SQL if it only allows text beginning with 'select' - those two statements seem contradictory?

Comment: If the editor requires you to use `SELECT` as the first word, then it doesn't accept PL/SQL code, pure and simple. And it won't even allow you to write standard SQL queries using old features that exist in the SQL Standard (and, therefore, in many database products) - for example the `WITH` clause. Drop that editor and choose something else; SQL Developer, for example, is excellent, and it's free.

Comment: @AlexPoole The only part of a standard PL/SQL block that I can run is the 'Begin' section and that has to start with Select, not Begin. In fact, i'm restricted from using semicolons in the code at all, so I'm probably mistaken in my explanation of the 'native' PL/SQL i'm using. But I'm trying to avoid repetition of fixed values, specifically dates that move around SYSDATE.

Comment: If it doesn't start with `declare` or `begin` then it isn't a PL/SQL block... it doesn't really sound like it allows anything except a simple query. Maybe if you include an example of what you want to do it might help. (And switching to a different client sounds like a good idea, if you can...)

Comment: Put all the "variables" you want to use in a subquery that is cross joined

Comment: You can't declare a variable at all in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially define your variables in a nested CTE:

```
select * from (
  -- CTE to define variables (sort of)
  with cte (some_date) as (
    select date '2018-12-31' from dual
  )
  -- your real query that joins to the CTE and used cte.some_date
  select d.*
  from cte
  cross join dual d
  where sysdate < cte.some_date
);
```

or more simply in an inline view:

```
select d.*
from (
  select date '2018-12-31' as some_date from dual
) t
cross join dual d
where sysdate < t.some_date;
```

Either way, `cte` or `t` is a single-row table so cross-joining makes its columns visible, but doesn't multiply the number of rows in the eventual result set (or rather, only multiplies it by 1, which is the same thing).

Whether your 'client' accepts either form is another matter...